# jobs command gives wrong output

Tags: ksh, job-control

I'm using Red Hat 6, and typing `jobs` gives me:

```
[2] + 12511
      12510      Running                 find . | xargs grep -i "string" >../a.txt
```

Those pids don't exist, and typing `fg %2` outputs:

```
find . | xargs grep -i "string" >../a.txt
```

I normally have no problems starting jobs, pushing them in the background, bringing them back into the foreground etc.  This has happened before, though.  I don't see the entries when I create another session.  Is there a command I can run to refresh whatever state is being confused here?  Is this an indication of a bigger problem?  I'm using ksh.

Comment: The output of `jobs` matches what it brings back in the foreground with `fg`, so I don't see what your real problem is.  Doesn't `ps -ef|grep find` show that `find` process?  If not, perhaps that part is done and it's still `grep`ing for your string in that huge directory listing.  `ps -ef|grep grep` would show it.

Comment: My real problem is just as described; jobs showing long dead processes. Find isn't running.  Both your ps|grep commands just show up the grep they invoke. My user only has 5 processes showing under ps; 2 ssh related, ksh and the ps/grep i'm using to display them.

Comment: Hmmm.  How about `ps -ef|grep "string"` where `string` is the initial search string you used, or `ps -ef|grep xargs` to see if it's stuck on `xargs`?

Comment: What version of ksh? Post the content of your `.kshrc`. Can you reproduce the problem reliably, or is it intermittent? If it happens in a shell, does it keep happening in the same shell for the same command? for all commands?

Comment: not stuck on xargs; no sign of the original string. Can't reproduce the problem on demand; it's happened only 2 or 3 times ever. Don't think I have a .kshrc.

Comment: my $SHELL points to /bin/ksh93